# CompletableFuture.get() outputs rather status than response body

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, httpclient, completable-future

I have the following scenario: I set up a client which sends an aynchronous HTTP reuqest to the server. The client receives a CompletableFuture. So far evertything works fine. However, I cannot access the response of the request I am sending.

```
completableFuture.get().body()
```

rather contains the status of the request. In more detail, I am getting

```
{"cancelled":false,"done":true,"completedExceptionally":false,"numberOfDependents":0}
```

How can I get the acutal result?

Here is my code...

Rest Controller

```
@RestController
public class WorkerJController {

    @Autowired
    private WorkerJService service;

    @GetMapping(value = "/JobList", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity> getJobListFunction() throws JsonProcessingException, InterruptedException {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(service.getJobListFunction()).thenApply(ResponseEntity::ok);
    }
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class WorkerJService {

    public static ArrayList<someThing> randomList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<String> getJobListFunction() throws JsonProcessingException, InterruptedException {
        randomList.add(new someThing("abc", "dfe"));
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(mapper.writeValueAsString(jobList));
    }
}
```

Async Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig {

    @Bean(name = "taskExecutor")
    public Executor taskExecutor(){
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(3);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(3);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("AsynchThread-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
```

I send the HTTP request as follows:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
        .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
        .followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.NORMAL)
        .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20))
        .build();

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/JobList"))
        .timeout(Duration.ofMinutes(2))
        .GET()
        .build();

CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<String>> cf = client
        .sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CompletableFuture.completedFuture(service.getJobListFunction())` wraps the `CompletableFuture` returned by `service.getJobListFunction()` into another `CompletableFuture`.

Just chain the response from the service directly with the `thenApply()` instead:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/JobList", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity> getJobListFunction() throws JsonProcessingException, InterruptedException {
    return service.getJobListFunction().thenApply(ResponseEntity::ok);
}
```